# How to interact with TF model in tfgo after importing

Tags: python, tensorflow, go

I followed the TensorFlow tutorial on https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/text_classification and saved the model.

I was able to successfully import into Go using the tfgo library:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    tg "github.com/galeone/tfgo"
    tf "github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go"
)

func main() {
    model := tg.LoadModel("movie_reviews", []string{"serve"}, nil)
    root := tg.NewRoot()
    t := tg.NewTensor(root, tg.Const(root, [3]int32{1, 2, 3}))
    fake, _ := tf.NewTensor([3]int32{1, 2, 3})
    model.Exec([]tf.Output{t.Output}, map[tf.Output]*tf.Tensor{
        model.Op("input", 0): fake,
    })
    fmt.Println(model)
}
```

But now I don't know how to interact with it. In Python you have all these model methods, i.e. `predict`, `evaluate`, etc.

With the Go binding it seems you need to know the exact operation name in order to interact with it?

How would I find out about that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using to Go bindings and tfgo you have to know the exact operation name.

Getting all the names, under the "serve" tags, by the way, it's straightforward using the `saved_model_cli` CLI tool, shipped together with the TensorFlow Python package.

```
saved_model_cli show --all --dir <path of your SavedModel>
```

It will give you all the information needed, for every tag available into the SavedModel. In your case, you have to give a look at the `signature_def` with the key "serve" or "serving_default".

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the tfgo package. I've also covered this topic in chapter 10 of the book Hands-On Neural networks with TensorFlow 2.0 - in the section dedicated to the SavedModel serialization format.